# What does <locals> mean in a function name?

Tags: python

Suppose I wrote a function that returns a function:

```
def my_func(word):
    def say():
        print(word)
    return say    
f = my_func("Hello!")

print(f)

<function my_func.<locals>.say at 0x7f39fb454840>
```

What is the meaning of `<locals>` here?

Comment: It means that the name `say` belongs to the local variables of `my_func`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Locals](https://www.journaldev.com/22946/python-locals) and [globals](https://www.journaldev.com/22870/python-globals) are symbol tables. When you run a python script, a list of all local identifiers i.e. symbols with scope limited to the current block (For e.g. a function) is maintained by the interpreter. This is what `<locals>` refers to in your output. Similarly, there is a list of all global identifiers called `globals`.

You can call `locals()` and `globals()` at any point in your code to get the corresponding symbol tables in a dictionary format